# How to clean the tweets having a specific but varying length pattern?

Tags: python, regex, twitter

I pulled out some tweets for analysis. When I separate the words in tweets I can see a lot of following expressions in my output:

```
\xe3\x81\x86\xe3\x81\xa1
```

I want to use regular expressions to replace these patterns with nothing. I am not very good with regex. I tried using solution in some similar questions but nothing worked for me. They are replacing characters like `"xt"` from `"extra"`.

I am looking for something that will replace `\x??` with nothing, considering `??` can be either `a`-`f` or `0`-`9` but word must be 4 letter and starting with `\x`.

Also i would like to add replacement for anything other than alphabets. Like:

```
"Hi!! my number is (7097868709809)."
```

after replacement should yield

```
"Hi my number is."
```

Input:

```
\xe3\x81\x86\xe3Extra
```

Output required:

```
Extra
```

Comment: What's the expected output for the above input?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added extra input to the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Sorry my bad. correcting the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is Unicode characters that can't directly be printed, expressed as pairs of hexadecimal digits. So for a more printable example:

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> hex(97)
'0x61'
>>> "\x61"
'a'
```

Note that what appears to be a sequence of four characters `'\x61'` evaluates to a single character, `'a'`. Therefore:

1. `??` can't *"be anything"* - they can be `'0'`-`'9'` or `'a'`-`'f'`; and
2. Although e.g. `r'\\x[0-9a-f]{2}'` would match the sequence you see, *that's not what the regex would parse* - each "word" is really a single character.

You can remove the characters *"other than alphabets"* using e.g. [`string.printable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.printable):

```
>>> s = "foo\xe3\x81"
>>> s
'foo\xe3\x81'
>>> import string
>>> valid_chars = set(string.printable)
>>> "".join([c for c in s if c in valid_chars])
'foo'
```

Note that e.g. `'\xe3'` *can* be directly printed in Python 3 (it's [`'ã'`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e3/index.htm)), but isn't included in `string.printable`. For more on Unicode in Python, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html).

Comment: That makes sense. I have one doubt though. Can we decode these unicode characters to get something more readable like 
>>> "\x61" get replaced by'a'

Comment: @VijayChhuttani as shown in my example using `'\x61'`, that is done automatically, where possible. You could write `s = '\x45\x78\x74\x72\x61'` and `print s` would show `'Extra'`!